# How to install SignalR in angular 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I would like to build real time application like live auction or chat app. I want to how to install and use SignalR in angular 4 + asp.net web api

Answer (score 0):

installation of packages:

```
npm install --save @aspnet/signalr
npm install --save @types/signalr
```

usage in client code:

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

this._connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/locationHub").build();
```

The client seems to be correctly connected but I wasn't able to receive messages from my server, still searching...

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the client as @nimbusparis said.

You have to build the server too, where you add the SignalR library via NuGet package. There are tons of samples, videos, etc... Just google for ".Net SignalR server", try some and come back with results (if bad). You have to point your client to your server obv. So if you are running your server on localhost port 3000 (for example), you should do this on client:

```
this._connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:3000").build();
```

You can google for "Angular 4 signalR client", i am pretty sure you will get nice results.

If you are using Visual Studio you can have both on the same project. Otherwise you need to develope them separately.

I recommend you .Net Core if you want to use .Net (not .Net Framework 4.x) as SignalR seems to be more focused to Core.

You don´t need .Net for doing this anyway, you can build the server with Express in Node and you can manage RTC with socket.io, but it just an example, there are tons of ways to get the server running (signalign server) without .Net in minutes.

To get this clear, you are building 2 apps unless you integrate Angular App on SignalR server in VS (the client is managed by the server).

I would use angular 6 if posible too.